# Pango-WARNING failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Noto Sans CJK JP 14'

Tags: fonts, debian, data-visualization, graphviz, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use Graphviz.
I use Windows 10, Windows Subsystems for Linux, Debian 10.
In my `dot` file I use Japanese, so I need to install Japanese font. I chose `noto` font.

I followed this instruction.
https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/

I did these commands.

```
    cd ~/Downloads
    unzip <font package>.zip
    sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto
    sudo cp *otf *otc /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto
    sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

This is my `vision.dot` file.

```
digraph vision {

  firebase[image="vision_image/firebase.png", label="Firebase：アプリ"];
  "Cloud Scheduler";
  firebase -> "Cloud Scheduler";

  bigquery[image="vision_image/bigquery.png", label="BigQuery：ビッグデータ"];
  "Apps Script";
  bigquery -> "Apps Script";


  tensorflow[image="vision_image/tensorflow.png", label="Tensorflow：AI"];
  Bert;
  Pegasus;
  Colaboratory;
  
  tensorflow -> Bert;
  tensorflow -> Pegasus;
  tensorflow -> Colaboratory;

  creativecloud[image="vision_image/Creative_Cloud.svg.png", label="Creative Cloud：アート"];

  Graphviz;
}
```

I did this command in my terminal.

```
dot -Kdot -Tpng vision.dot -ovision17.png
```

I got this output in my terminal.

```
(process:2409): Pango-WARNING **: 14:37:40.578: failed to create cairo scaled font, 
expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Noto Sans CJK JP 14'

(process:2409): Pango-WARNING **: 14:37:40.579: font_face status is: file not found

(process:2409): Pango-WARNING **: 14:37:40.590: scaled_font status is: file not found

(process:2409): Pango-WARNING **: 14:37:40.593: shaping failure, expect ugly output. 
shape-engine='PangoFcShapeEngine', font='Noto Sans CJK JP 14', text='?'
```

And this is vision17.png file. Japanese is not displayed properly.

Could you give me any advice, please?
[image]

Comment: On windows (dot version 2.38) I do see the that the Japanese characters are not shown, but I don't get the warning (just warnings about the missing images but that is irrelevant here). When I try it with the Cygwin dot executable (version 2.40) I do see the Japanese characters . On Windows I installed the Noto font as indicated as well on Windows, on Cygwin there are already some Noto fonts installed. So my idea is that it is either the version of `dot` or that `dot` cannot find the font. Did you set anywhere the font to `Noto Sans CJK JP 14` as I don't get that message.

Comment: @albert Thank you very much for your detailed advice. I will check and try your advice on Monday, so just a moment please.

Comment: @albert My `dot` version is `dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)` I have tried in several ways, but I couldn't solve. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.